# sidebar when select menu make it active class by changing the backgroundcolor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

iam trying to make a side bar for selcted menu i want to make the menu link active by changing the backgroundcolour of the link  using `listItemActive`

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faCog,
  faThLarge,
  faBriefcaseMedical,
  faSms,
  faQrcode,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";


export default class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    function hideBar() {
      var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
      sidebar.classList.remove("show");
      sidebar.classList.add("hide");
    }
    return (
      <div className="sidebar" style={styles.header}>
        <a class="close-icon" href="#" onClick={hideBar}>
          &#10006;
        </a>
        <img src={Logo} alt="" />
        <ul style={styles.lists}>
          <Link to="/client" >
            <li
              activeClassName="active"
              style={styles.listItemActive}
              ctiveClassName="active"
            >
              <div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faThLarge}
                  style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                />
              </div>
              <div> Dashboard</div>
            </li>
          </Link>

          <Link to="/cdoctor" >
            <li style={styles.listItem}>
              {" "}
              <div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faBriefcaseMedical}
                  style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                />
              </div>
              <div> Doctor</div>
            </li>
          </Link>

          {/* <li style={styles.listItem}>
            <div>
              <i
                className="fa fa-product-hunt"
                style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
              ></i>
            </div>
            <div> Products</div>
          </li> */}

          <li style={styles.listItem}>
            <div>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSms} style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }} />
            </div>
            <div>Messages</div>
          </li>

          <Link to="/cscan">
            <li style={styles.listItem}>
              <div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  icon={faQrcode}
                  style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>Upcoming Scans</div>
            </li>
          </Link>
        </ul>
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: "3rem",
            left: "30px",
            width: "15%",
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
            <button
              style={{
                color: "#fff",
                textDecoration: "none",
                background: "transparent",
                border: "none",
              }}
            >
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} style={{ marginRight: "1rem" }} />
              Settings
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  header: {
    // background: "linear-gradient(25deg, #3a51a7, #7f1f54)",
    background:
      " 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box padding-box rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11)",
    padding: "2rem",
    // minHeight: "100%",
    // height: "100vh",
    width: "20%",
    margin: "0",
    color: "white",
  },
  lists: {
    marginTop: "5rem",
    color: "#fff",
    paddingLeft: "0",
    listStyle: "none",
  },
  listItem: {
    background: "transparent",
    padding: "10px 50px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    textAlign: "initial",
    display: "flex",
  },
  listItemActive: {
    background: "#6a0f4b",
    padding: "10px 50px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    cursor: "pointer",
    display: "flex",
  },
};
```